# How a string could be of type interface{}

Tags: go, interface

I am currently learning `go` after `C++`. I just get stuck every time while facing `interface`.
e.g:

```
s := []interface{}{"a", "b", "c"}
```

How string could be an interface?

I am not getting in what sense interface is introduced in `go`. There are many more doubts regarding interface.

Answer to the above question and especially providing some learning resources regarding interface would be great.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: See [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/methods/9) (the page on [empty interface](https://tour.golang.org/methods/14) is very relevant here), [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go#interfaces) and the [specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types).

Answer (score 4):

By definition, an interface is defined as a set of method signatures. So it is used to indicate which methods should be implemented by another type. If the interface doesn't specify any method signatures in the interface declaration body then any valid type can be of the type of that interface since there are no prerequisites of being that interface.

In your example, the slice contains a type of `interface{}` meaning any type can be a valid candidate as the slice input.

```
s := []interface{}{"a", 1, false}
```

https://tour.golang.org/methods/9 is a good place for exploring and learning `go`.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of an interface as a container that holds a value and the type of that value.

When you define your own interfaces the compiler will ensure that the values you assign (store in the interface) have methods that match what you specified in your interface definition.

Empty interfaces, `interface{}`, have no methods and can therefore store any value since there are no expectations for the existence of any particular methods.

If you have not already, check the section on interfaces in [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/methods/9).